# Properly Attaching a Backbone.Marionette LayoutView to the Application

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to use the [marionette inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/marionette-inspector/fbgfjlockdhidoaempmjcddibjklhpka), but the inspector can not find my views, presumably [because they are not properly attached to the Application](https://github.com/marionettejs/marionette.inspector/issues/231).  What do I need to do to register an instance of `Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView` with a instance of `Backbone.Marionette.Application`?

Here is my current code (in coffeescript), which does not properly attach the view:

```
App = Backbone.Marionette.Application.extend({
    initialize: (options) ->
        console.log("App Initialized")
        LayoutView = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
            el: '#app'
            template: (data) ->
                return "<section>
                    <navigation id='menu'>...</navigation>
                    <article id='content'>...</article>
                  </section>"
            regions:
                menu: "#menu"
                content: "#content"
        })
        layoutView = new LayoutView()
        layoutView.render()
        sampleModel = new Backbone.Model(name: "test")
});


app = new App({container: '#app'})
app.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question was answered by the helpful folks at the [marionette-inspector github page](https://github.com/marionettejs/marionette.inspector/issues/231).

```
App = Backbone.Marionette.Application.extend({
    initialize: (options) ->
        console.log("App Initialized")
        LayoutView = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
            el: '#app'
            template: '#main_template'
            regions:
                menu: "#menu"
                content: "#content"
        })
        @rootView = new LayoutView()
```